# Does data point ordering matter in LASSO regression?

Tags: regression, python, linear-model, lasso

I am working with [Lasso](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.Lasso.html) on Python with a dataset of size 85×2000. I find that the ordering of the rows influence the result of the Lasso run.

I have other parameters fixed, including random states so that each run is determined. The hyperparameter is chosen through cross validation (using [LassoCV](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LassoCV.html) in Python). However, the results change still. Is this because of the CV, or I am doing something wrong ?

Comment: LASSO usually involves some cross-validation to choose an optimal penalty value. Even with the "fixed random states," might the re-ordering of the rows affect which cases are included in which folds of that cross-validation? Please add that information to your question rather than just responding with a comment, as comments can be lost sometimes and are harder to see in any event.

Comment: Thanks for updating the question. When you say "the results change" does that mean that the chosen penalty hyperparameter differs with the re-ordering of the rows, or does the same penalty choice lead to a different selection of predictors? Is this a regular linear regression or a generalized linear model like a logistic regression? What's your choice for CV error, and are you using the minimum-CV error or the 1-standard-error criterion? Also, you seem to have set up 2 accounts; see [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) for how to merge them.

Comment: If @EdM is right, it's due to the CV, then the results should differ for different runs as well. You can test this out and see whether the distribution of the outcomes is different for a different order of columns.